# what shape would a planet entirely dedicated to watching be

Tags: planets, space, aliens, solar-system, fear

If I have a planet fully dedicated to watching (think the Eye from Magnus Archives) what shape would allow for constant observation of the whole planet from some sort of tower

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking. Planets are spherical by definition, and it's simply impossible to directly see the entire surface of any 3D object from any vantage point - you can never see a body's whole surface from anywhere, no matter what shape the body is or where you're looking from.

Comment: Wdym by "entirely dedicated to watching"????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Same as we have right now, a flat Earth

Comment: Even a flat earth doesn't work. It can extend far enough that something can't be observed from the tower. Worse, every mountain range blocks the view. I'm voting for a planetary version of a [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere), meaning the world is hollow. This is the only planetary structure that maximizes your goal, but it requires magic (traditional or [Clarkean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws)) to exist.

Comment: Also, for the future, one-sentence questions are frowned upon (a lot) on Stack Exchange. You're expected to provide at least a paragraph or two explaining your specific problem, any conditions and/or limitations that exist (they should), and your goals or expectations for a best answer. You heard from SE's automated Community BOT because your one-sentence question failed SE's basic "good question" heuristics. Check out [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask] for more about writing questions.

Comment: Surely the answer is Halo. You want a ring-world where you can observe pretty much everything from pretty much anywhere as long as you (and what you are observing) are  on the inside of the ring.